# getting a certain group from regex match

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a .txt file with some text (copied from an edifact file) and i wanted to match certain fields, I basically just want the date (match 1, group 0)

this is the regex that I have 
https://regex101.com/r/oSVlS8/6

but I cant implement it in my code, I only want group 0 of the match.

here is my code:

```
regex = r"^((?:INV)\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){4})\d{8}"
with open ("test edifakt 1 bk v1.txt", "r") as f:
    result = re.findall(regex,f.read(),re.MULTILINE)
    print(result)
```

and this is what i get as a result:

```
['INV+ED Format 1+Brustkrebs+19880117+E000000001+']
```

I actually want "20080702" instead

I tried things like `print(result.group(0))`, but that didn't work. I got:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'`

I also tried it as an argument like this `result = re.findall(regex,f.read(),group(0),re.MULTILINE)`      but I get
 `get NameError: name 'group' is not defined`

can I really only match a certain group if I'm using `re.search` and its a string?

Comment: Try switching the groups `\bINV\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){4}(\d{8})` https://regex101.com/r/i5MedI/1 and the value will be in group 1

Comment: `re.findall() returns a list`, so, if you want the first group match, you get it with `re.findall()[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the capturing group to capture the digits instead.

**Note** that you can omit the non capturing group around INV `(?:INV)` and using `*` as the quantifier for `[^+\n]*\+` could possibly also match 4 consecutive plus signs ++++

```
^INV\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){4}(\d{8})
```

- `^` Start of string
- `INV\+` match INV+
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^+\n]*\+` Match 0+ times any char except a `+` or newline
- `){4}` Close group and repeat 4 times
- `(\d{8})` Capture **group 1**, match 8 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3F3Bt8/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xeOKnO)

For example

```
regex = r"^INV\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){4}(\d{8})"
result = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

Output

```
['20080702']
```

---

If you want to use the group method, you could use

```
matches = re.search(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE) 
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
20080702
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/POX2j3)

---

- [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return the value of the capture group.
- [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will return a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) which has a group method.

Comment: The answer is right but judging by the description on the OP, the user will still have trouble because he wants the string. He is looking for `result[0]` instead of simply `result`. :-)

Comment: @accdias Thank you for the comment. I have added another example to use re.search

Comment: thanks! I had not though about changing the expression itself, and this worked :D
and I wanted to keep using the re.findall function instead of search so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
re.search(r'(?:INV)\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){4}(\d{8})', text).group(1)
```

Returns

```
'20080702'
```

Comment: thank you, that worked but what I have is a file object not a string, is having it in string the only way?

Comment: No, just replace the regex in your `result = re.findall(regex,f.read(),re.MULTILINE)` with the one that I gave you

Comment: i tried it, it didn't work, and i think that's because i have a file object, and not a string, so when i tried it i got     NameError: name 'text' is not defined

Comment: this did however work when I pasted the content into a string "text", so I'm upvoting ^^